# Android program fails. No errors, no log cat. No clues

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

Pardon the nebulous nature of this question.  But I am out of patience and have no clues.  The error is the infamous "Unfortunately (your program) has stopped".

I am running relatively simple exercise program in Eclipse involving the actionbar and tabs.  However, I am not posting the source because my program fails before it ever gets to my actual code.  I toggled a breakpoint on my first "breakable" line of code; it never trips.  There are no exceptions in the LogCat, and no errors on the Console.  The Variable window shows a "NullPointerException" on variable "e".  The source window states "Source Not Found" though I understand that is a generic error and doesn't necessarily mean anything.

I have cleaned, built, saved, restarted, rebooted.  I have tested other more complex programs successfully.  I have deleted the \bin and the debug.keystore files and rebuilt.  Nothing I do gives me a different error or any better clues as to what to look for.

I'm no guru, but I can generally make my own way through java code.  But I'm out of ideas here.  Can any point me in the right direction?

Comment: if you are getting a NullPointerException then there has to be a stack trace of the error in the logcat

Comment: "NullPointerException" on variable "e", this could lead to obfuscated source (e is a variable that has been obfuscated).

Comment: The problem is not in your application but in the emulator you're using. Try creating a new project and execute it in this emulator and check if it has the same error.

Comment: What is the first "breakable" line of code?   Member initialization in your Activity class?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new hello world application.   Make sure it runs.

Copy the code from the existing application to the new application in very small chunks.   Keep going 'till you add something that breaks the new app, or the new app is a complete copy of the old app that works.

If it breaks, you know know what did it (not necessarily why, yet, but you know where to look.)

If it doesn't break you have a working app!  Now you needed do decide how curious you are -- how much time to spend playing "what's the difference between these two pictures." verses moving on with the project.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your advice.  That at least earned me some progress. The culprit appears to be "actionBar.addTab(tab);" I still have no idea why.  I know this simple line was working just days ago.  I was putting the final touches on one of the tab fragments when all this happened. Any ideas?  If not that's okay, you gave me the answer that I came to this forum looking for.  Thank you!